# instruction's argument order

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, att

dump of assembler code for function main:

```
0x0000000100000de6 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000100000de7 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000100000dea <main+4>:    sub    $0x30,%rsp
0x0000000100000dee <main+8>:    mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
```

I learned `mov %rsp,%rbp` means `move the value of rsp to rbp`
But I knew in Intel architecture, that would mean `move the value of rbp to rsp`
According to Intel manual(Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual. Volume 2. 3-104 MOV instruction), `mov a, b` should mean `move b to a`

Next `sub` instuction is the same.
I knew `sub a,b` means `a = a-b`. But here `sub $0x30, %rsp` means `rsp = rsp - 0x30`

What's wrong with me?

Comment: `%` everywhere, nonsensical memory syntax, and an instruction that should be impossible. All points to AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing's wrong with you. What you have presented here is assembly code in AT&T syntax (google it up), in which the operand order is the opposite to what you see in the Intel manuals.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexey! From your help, I googled this document. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972602/att-vs-intel-syntax-and-limitations  Thank you again!