# What does 0x4 from cmp 0x4(%esi),%ebx assembly instruction mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, g++, att

What does `0x4` from the following assembly line mean?

```
cmp 0x4(%esi),%ebx
je ...
```

When this compare returns equal and the jump is performed the registers have the values:
`%esi` `0xe944d6d0`
`%ebx` `0xe94ceccc`

Sorry for asking such a simple question but I'm having a hard time searching such paranthesis notation with google. Spent more than half an hour while under time pressure.

Comment: If you aren't comfortable with AT&T syntax, you can switch to Intel syntax.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/972614/1354557

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is this line doing: add -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848554/what-exactly-is-this-line-doing-add-0x4esi-ebx-4-eax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is AT&T syntax, in Intel syntax it would be:

```
cmp ebx,[esi+4]
```

Note that the order of operands is reversed.

In Intel syntax it's dest, src. In AT&T it's src, dest.

So basically that instruction compares `ebx` with the dword value stored in `[esi+4]` by subtracting the dword value stored in `[esi+4]` from `ebx`, just like `sub` would do, but `cmp` only updates flags, it doesn't store the result anywhere.